# Plotly Subplots: IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I am trying to run the Plotly tutorial to make subplots on (https://plot.ly/python/creating-and-updating-figures/):

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=[4, 2, 1], mode="lines"), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(y=[2, 1, 3]), row=2, col=1)
fig.show()
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      1 from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
      2 fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)
----> 3 fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=[4, 2, 1], mode="lines"), row=1, col=1)
      4 fig.add_trace(go.Bar(y=[2, 1, 3]), row=2, col=1)
      5 fig.show()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\quantlib\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in add_trace(self, trace, row, col)
   1070         # ----------------
   1071         for key_path_str, v in restyle_data.items():
-> 1072 
   1073             # Track whether any of the new values are cause a change in
   1074             # self._data

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\quantlib\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in add_traces(self, data, rows, cols)
   1153         # In batch mode
   1154         # -------------
-> 1155         # Add key_path_str/val to saved batch edits
   1156         else:
   1157             if trace_index not in self._batch_trace_edits:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\quantlib\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in _set_trace_grid_position(self, trace, row, col)
   1254 
   1255     @staticmethod
-> 1256     def _set_in(d, key_path_str, v):
   1257         """
   1258         Set a value in a nested dict using a key path string

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Any ideas how to correct? Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is `go.` ?

Comment: sorry, this is Plotly. `import plotly.graph_objects as go`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the `list` as a `tuple` :

```py
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
### specify it next time
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=tuple([4, 2, 1]), mode="lines"), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(y=tuple([2, 1, 3])), row=2, col=1)
fig.show()
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. When I ran your code, I still got the error. Updating to Plotly 4.0 allowed me to run it. After I updated, your code works but so does the original. Thank you for helping me get to the bottom of it.